# "Configure Windows machines to be associated with a Data Collection Rule" Azure policy is not working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-policy

I am deploying ["Configure Windows machines to be associated with a Data Collection Rule"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Monitoring/AzureMonitor_DCRA_Windows_Deploy.json) policy to my VMs in a resource group. But the remediation task completes without making any changes and reports - "0 resources selected for remediation".
We use custom VM images and not Azure published ones. And every month a new image with latest patches is published for use.
Looking at policy definition I see things like:

```
            "anyOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageId",
            "in": "[parameters('listOfWindowsImageIdToInclude')]"
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
                "equals": "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageOffer",
                "equals": "WindowsServer"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imageSKU",
                "in": [
                  "2008-R2-SP1",
                  "2008-R2-SP1-smalldisk",
                  "2012-Datacenter",
                  "2012-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2012-R2-Datacenter",
                  "2012-R2-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter",
                  "2016-Datacenter-Server-Core",
                  "2016-Datacenter-Server-Core-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2016-Datacenter-with-Containers",
                  "2016-Datacenter-with-RDSH",
                  "2019-Datacenter",
                  "2019-Datacenter-Core",
                  "2019-Datacenter-Core-smalldisk",
                  "2019-Datacenter-Core-with-Containers",
                  "2019-Datacenter-Core-with-Containers-smalldisk",
                  "2019-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                  "2019-Datacenter-with-Containers",
                  "2019-Datacenter-with-Containers-smalldisk",
                  "2019-Datacenter-zhcn"
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
```

Does that mean it is only applying to Azure images and not our custom images?
The policy has a parameter called "Optional: List of virtual machine images that have supported Windows OS to add to scope ", which I left blank as the imageid will change every month.
Is this causing the problem? Or something else?

Comment: Please share the whole policy condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this policy definition only applies to a set of Azure images with known support for this feature, and those specified in the *listOfWindowsImageIdToInclude* parameter. If you want this policy to apply to VMs created from custom images, then you must either update the *listOfWindowsImageIdToInclude* parameter once a month, or duplicate the policy and modify the *if* condition in a way that it will apply to your VMs.